# Git terminal in Windows, openshift.redhat rhc setup password/terminal fail

Tags: git

I try setting `rhc setup` for the first time.
but Git terminal is causes problems for me

```
Johan@jh-surface MINGW64 /c
$ rhc setup
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace, and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.

If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just hit enter to use the server for OpenShift Online: openshift.redhat.com.
Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com|
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility

You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.

Login to openshift.redhat.com: jp-hamanz@gmail.com
Password: ***********
```

Here I press `Ctrl+c` after some time

```
Johan@jh-surface MINGW64 /c
$ ***********
bash: ***********: command not found

Johan@jh-surface MINGW64 /c
$

Johan@jh-surface MINGW64 /c
$ ^C

Johan@jh-surface MINGW64 /c
```

**Update**: 

 Well I ended up using Windows cmd. so it probably has something to do with Git Bash